Running python script as .py file
I have a bunch of Python commands that I can use to download, unzip and rename files. I need to download about 100 files every couple of months, so I would like to automate this, but I am new to Python and can't figure out how to do it.
So, firstly, how do I run the following script as a .py file (which as I understand is the easiest way to do it)?
The "with zipfile.Zipfile..." command requires me to press enter after I enter the command, which I assume can cause an issue when executing the .py file, how do I avoid this problem?
I tried following instructions from websites, but there is something really basic that I fail to understand in the running of a .py file. Can I run it both in PowerShell and in the Python terminal?
>>>os.chdir("C:\\Pythonfolder\\Geodata")

>>>from urllib.request import urlretrieve

>>>url = ("https://ext-dokument.lansstyrelsen.se/gemensamt/geodata/ShapeExport/lst.Riks_slutforvaring.zip")

>>>filename = "Slutforvaring.zip"

>>>urlretrieve(url, filename)

>>>import zipfile

>>>with zipfile.ZipFile("Slutforvaring.zip", "r") as zip_ref: zip_ref.extractall("ZIP, Riksintresse Slutförvaring")

>>>... !PRESS ENTER

>>>import os

>>>os.rename("ZIP, Riksintresse Slutförvaring\\lst.Riks_slutforvaring.gpkg","Länsstyrelserna, Riksintresse Slutförvaring.gpkg")


Create a new text file, rename it to whatever.py, open in text editor, paste the stuff above (without the >>>). Put the imports on top and clean up. You may have to tweak things here and there, an IDE may help you. Don't worry about the extra enter, that's only in an interactive session, not when running from a file.

Usually, you'd either open cmd or PowerShell and type either the script name whatever.py or pass it to the Python interpreter as python whatever.py.

To create a Python script from your commands, follow the following outline:

create a new text file
rename it to whatever.py (probably Explorer will cry that the file may become unusable, ignore it)
open the file and paste your Python statements (omitting the leading >>>)
clean up: move the import statements to the top and adjust indentation

After this, you would have a file looking somewhat like below. Note that the first six lines including the docstring are optional and you won't need them. It's just good practice and increases portability. A docstring tells your teammates or future-you what this script does and how it should be used.
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
"""
A docstring that explains what this script does.
This is optional but you may find it helpful later.
"""

import os
import zipfile
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

os.chdir("C:\\Pythonfolder\\Geodata")
url = ("https://ext-dokument.lansstyrelsen.se/gemensamt/geodata/ShapeExport/lst.Riks_slutforvaring.zip")
filename = "Slutforvaring.zip"
urlretrieve(url, filename)
with zipfile.ZipFile("Slutforvaring.zip", "r") as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall("ZIP, Riksintresse Slutförvaring")

os.rename("ZIP, Riksintresse Slutförvaring\\lst.Riks_slutforvaring.gpkg", "Länsstyrelserna, Riksintresse Slutförvaring.gpkg")

Having to press Enter in the interactive Python shell comes from the fact that with zipile...: starts a block. This is Python asking you "anything else you want me to do in that block?" and pressing Enter again tells Python "no, that's all".
In the file, this is expressed through the change in indentation. The indented line is part of the block and everything else isn't.
Typically, you would run this from either cmd or PowerShell with either of the two commands:
whatever.py
python whatever.py

If it fails, double-check the directory with your Python executable is in your PATH environment variable.
You may also find the tutorial Run Python Scripts on Real Python helpful.
Try out a few IDEs and pick one you like. You should be able to run your code from it. Furthermore, it should run linters in the background that check your code while you type. This greatly speeds up finding programming errors.
By the way, if the URL you download from or the file name tends to change, you may want to pass them as command line arguments. See into sys.argv or Python's argparse module for more information.

Great, thank you, works like a charm! The path environment variable tip was great.

what you are using is the interactive shell or the python IDLE in which indented statements such as a conditional for and if have automatic indentation as explained here. you escape this using the enter key or by using specific keywords such as break or return.

firstly, how do I run the following script as a .py file

As Friedrich suggested u can paste your code statements in a new file (or write it all down it isnt really much), clean it up a bit, save it as your_script.py or something, and run it using the IDE. if you prefer terminal, then
python3.9 your_script.py

replace 3.9 with whatever python version you're using
